# Accepted invite for github project but cannot find it anywhere on my github?

Tags: github

Silly question probably but I find github not that user friendly for beginners. I was invited to join a group and project, accepted the invitation through my email which took me directly to their page. If I ever leave the page and want to find out how to get back to it, there is absolutely no way/notifications for me to find that page ever.

Even when I type their username in search, their project is private but I clearly have access to it so I cannot find their project in their repository to get back to it. How does this make sense? Where do you go from your github page to find all projects/repos that you are a part of and have access to?

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the GitHub search engine doesn't index private repositories by default; that would pose a security risk.

- All repositories you are a manager or owner of can be found by
  clicking your profile picture in the upper-right corner and clicking
  "Your Repositories."
- **Starring** the repository will save the repository to your starred list, which will improve your recommendations, make it appear in your
  Starred list on your profile page, and in many cases, enable the
  repository to appear as a search suggestion when you type the
  repository into the search bar. You can do it by visiting the
  repository and clicking the star icon in the upper-right.
- **Watching** the repository will subscribe you to notifications. You can do it by visiting the repository and clicking the eyeball icon in
  the upper-right.